# cvxopt uses just one core, need to run on all / some

Tags: glpk, cvxopt

I call `cvxopt.glpk.ilp` in Python 3.6.6, cvxopt==1.2.3 for a boolean optimization problem with about 500k boolean variables. It is solved in 1.5 hours, but it seems to run on just one core! How can I make it run on all or a specific set of cores?

The server with Linux Ubuntu x86_64 has 16 or 32 physical cores. My process affinity is 64 cores (I assume due to hyperthreading).

```
> grep ^cpu\\scores /proc/cpuinfo | uniq
16
> grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
64
> taskset -cp <PID>
pid <PID> current affinity list:  0-63
```

However `top` shows only 100% CPU for my process, and `htop` shows that only one core is 100% busy (some others are slightly loaded presumably by other users).

I set `OMP_NUM_THREADS=32` and started my program again, but still one core. It's a bit difficult to restart the server itself. I don't have root access to the server.

I installed `cvxopt` from a company's internal repo which should be a mirror of PyPI. The following libs are installed in `/usr/lib`: `liblapack, liblapack_atlas, libopenblas, libblas, libcblas, libatlas`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40096396/2320035) some SO-user writes, that [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) is not multithreaded. This is the solver used by default as cvxopt has no own MIP-solver.

As cvxopt [only supports](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#optional-solvers) GLPK as open-source mixed-integer programming solver, you are out of luck.

Alternatively you can use CoinOR's [Cbc](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc), which is usually a much better solver than GLPK while still being open-source. This one also can be compiled with parallelization. See [some benchmarks](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/milp.html) which also indicate that GLPK is really without parallel support.

But as there is no support in cvxopt, you will need some alternative access-point:

- own C/C++ based wrapper
- [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp)

  - binary install available
- [python-mip](https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip)

  - binary install available
- [Google's ortools](https://github.com/google/or-tools)

  - binary install available
- [cylp](https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP)
- [cvxpy + cylp](https://www.cvxpy.org/index.html)

  - binary install available for cvxpy; without cylp-build

Those:

- have very different modelling-styles (from completely low-level: cylp to very high-level: cvxpy)
- i'm not sure if all those builds are compiled with *enable-parallel* (which is needed when compiling Cbx)

Furthermore: don't expect too much gain from multithreading. It's usually way worse than linear speedup (as for all combinatorial-optimization problems which are not based on brute-force).

(Imho the GIL does not matter as all those are C-extensions where the GIL is not in the way)